# Build a checkbox method for every item

Tags: flutter

i want to create a simple method _buildCheckListItem which allows to build many list item, a Row with a Text and a Checkbox. 
In the ui, when i click on checkbox, the ui doesn't change and the value printed on console are always true. How to solve that?

Here the variable for every checkbox:

```
 bool chkLavoro = false;
 bool chkSvago = false;
 bool chkCultura = false;
 bool chkBenessere = false;
 bool chkViaggioNozze = false;
 bool chkSalute = false;
 bool chkCicloViaggiatore = false;
 bool chkWeekend = false;



Widget _buildCheckListItem(String label, bool motivo) {
return Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: <Widget>[
    Text(
      label,
      style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
        fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
        fontSize: 14,
      ),
    ),
    Checkbox(
      value: motivo,
         onChanged: (bool value) {
        setState(() {
          motivo = value;
          print('$label e $motivo');
        });
      },
    ),
  ],
);}
```

The call is something like this:

```
 Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _buildCheckListItem('Lavoro', chkLavoro),
                    _buildCheckListItem('Svago', chkSvago),
                    _buildCheckListItem('Cultura', chkCultura),
                    _buildCheckListItem('Benessere', chkBenessere),
                    _buildCheckListItem(
                        'Viaggio di nozze', chkViaggioNozze),
                    _buildCheckListItem('Salute', chkSalute),
                    _buildCheckListItem(
                        'Cicloviaggiatore', chkCicloViaggiatore),
                    _buildCheckListItem('Weekend fuori porta', chkWeekend),
                  ],
                )
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb4pc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Remove type on the value. check code beneath:

```
onChanged: (value) {
  setState(() {
    motivo = value;
    print('$label e $motivo');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is when **setState** is called, it rebuilds everything in your Widget which means it rebuilds the **Column**, therefore, recalling the **_buildCheckListem** with boolean values that haven't changed.

You can solve this by creating a new Widget like this

```
class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            CheckListItem('Lavoro', chkLavoro),
            CheckListItem('Svago', chkSvago),
            CheckListItem('Cultura', chkCultura),
            CheckListItem('Benessere', chkBenessere),
            CheckListItem('Viaggio di nozze', chkViaggioNozze),
            CheckListItem('Salute', chkSalute),
            CheckListItem('Cicloviaggiatore', chkCicloViaggiatore),
            CheckListItem('Weekend fuori porta', chkWeekend),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  bool chkLavoro = false;
  bool chkSvago = false;
  bool chkCultura = false;
  bool chkBenessere = false;
  bool chkViaggioNozze = false;
  bool chkSalute = false;
  bool chkCicloViaggiatore = false;
  bool chkWeekend = false;
}

class CheckListItem extends StatefulWidget {
  bool value;
  String label;

  CheckListItem(this.label, this.value);

  @override
  _CheckListItemState createState() => _CheckListItemState();
}

class _CheckListItemState extends State<CheckListItem> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          widget.label,
        ),
        Checkbox(
          value: widget.value,
          onChanged: (bool value) {
            setState(() {
              widget.value = value;
              print('${widget.label} e ${widget.value}');
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```